# Simple XML unmarshalling return empty values

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I'm trying a unmarshal some basic XML in Go. I've been able to unmarshal very large XML files in Go before, so the issue I have here really baffles me.

Unmarshalling finds one item, as it should, but all values are to their null default: strings are empty and the float is zero.

Any hint would help. Thanks.

#### XML

```
<config><throttle delay="20" unit="s" host="feeds.feedburner.com"/></config>
```

#### Output

`host:"", unit:"", delay:0.000000`

#### Code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

// Config allows for unmarshling of the remote configuration file.
type Config struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name     `xml:"config"`
    Throttlers []*Throttler `xml:"throttle"`
}

// Throttler stores the throttle information read from the configuration file.
type Throttler struct {
    host  string  `xml:"host,attr"`
    unit  string  `xml:"unit,attr"`
    delay float64 `xml:"delay,attr"`
}

func main() {

    data := `
        <config><throttle delay="20" unit="s" host="feeds.feedburner.com"/></config>
    `
    config := Config{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %config", err)
        return
    }
    thr := config.Throttlers[0]
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("host:%q, unit:%q, delay:%f", thr.host, thr.unit, thr.delay))

}
```

[Go playground link here](http://play.golang.org/p/Hcaw4geHxp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as trivially, the `Throttler` struct doesn't export its fields. Hence, changing the struct to have upper case variables makes them accessible.

[Fixed example here](http://play.golang.org/p/IzWsfRKZdI)